# Use boost::async w/o c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost

I have to use gcc 4.8.3 w/o C++11. Without C++11, boost 1.56 `async` and `future` work differently. I guess `boost::async` returns `boost::unique_future` by default. W/ C++11, `unique_future` can be moved to `shared_future`. So I can do

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
void do() {}
boost::shared_future<void> f = boost::async(do);
std::vector<boost::shared_future<void>> fs;
fs.push_back(f);
```

W/o C++11, what macros do we need to make the same code? I guess we need to call boost 'move' explicitly? Otherwise, the returned future cannot be 'casted' to a shared future.

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USES_MOVE
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
boost::unique_future<void> f = boost::async(boost::launch::any, do);
```

But I am not sure how to 'move' f to an `std::vector`. Do we need more macros to make this work?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly share a future using the [`share()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.share) member function (not sure when it was added, but it's definitely in Boost.Thread 1.56):

```
boost::shared_future<void> f = boost::async(do).share();
```

Shared futures are copyable so you don't need to use move semantics. If you do decide to use move semantics under C++03, you would have to [use Boost.Move-aware containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/move/move_and_containers.html) i.e. replace `std::vector` with `boost::container::vector`:

```
boost::unique_future<void> f = boost::async(do);
boost::container::vector<boost::unique_future<void>> fs;
fs.push_back(boost::move(f));
```